# add_settings_section() order

Tags: settings-api

I made on a custom theme for a client. For this theme I created a settings page so that the client could edit some variables to his liking. This part is working properly.

For this same site, I created a custom post type as a plugin. I need the client to be able to edit some variables for this custom post type as well. So, I would like my plugin to add an other settings section to my settings page. I’m using this code in my plugin:

```
function dr_issue_settings_init() {

    add_settings_section(
        'dr_issue_section', //$id
        __( 'Issue settings' ), //title
        'dr_issue_section_callback', //callback
        'mytheme_settings' // page
    );

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'dr_issue_settings_init' );
```

The problem is; this section appears before the theme settings I created before.
In the global $wp_settings_sections this plugin section is the first value of the array, before the theme section.

How can I make my plugin section be underneath the theme section?

Comment: Would you please edit your question to include all of the code for the settings page? I think changing the priority would do the trick, but it would help to see the theme's settings code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the priority of `dr_issue_settings_init()` so that it fires after the default of 10. This should make it appear after the existing settings on the same settings page.

```
function dr_issue_settings_init() {

    add_settings_section(
        'dr_issue_section', //$id
        __( 'Issue settings' ), //title
        'dr_issue_section_callback', //callback
        'mytheme_settings' // page
    );

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'dr_issue_settings_init', 100 );
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, it indeed was the priority.